# Why didn't Admiral Ackbar recognize Luke Skywalker's name in Return of the Jedi

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, the-clone-wars

Since Admiral Ackbar fought alongside Anakin Skywalker during the Clone Wars (e.g. shown in *Star Wars the Clone Wars season 4, episode 1*) why didn't he recognize Luke Skywalker's name in *Return of the Jedi* (or before if they met)? Did he just keep it to himself or did he figure out that Luke was Anakin's son?

Comment: What makes you *think* he didn't just because it wasn't shown? How do you know he didn't ask him about his father when they were off duty? Though, it was of course because the *Clone Wars* weren't written yet. I'm not sure we ought look for all kinds of tiny and entirely irrelevant inconsistencies like that or expect Lucas to put in a nice chatting scene between Luke and one of his father's acquaintances on the café deck in the next revision of the film.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson "... in the next revision of the film"  LOL.  It's funny because it's probably true.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson my goal is not to find plotholes. I was just wondering if there was any explanation to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the original trilogy, they didn't meet before Return of the Jedi. And they don't even meet actually. Luke joins the party when all plans were explained and everybody was preparing for the battle. So, even if he saw him, he couldn't know his name. Leia, Han, Chewbacca and Luke leave right after this meeting.

Comment: And new, made-up stories (canon books) aside, what would prompt anyone to know who Leia really was anyway?  She never changed her name to Skywalker and Han (and Chewie perhaps?) would be the only ones to know.  Outside of some rumor or conjecture, unless it was addressed off-screen, the general public wouldn't even know who Kylo Ren is and if they did they couldn't know his Skywalker heritage without it being formally acknowledged.  And in the films, we don't see that.